# Can we add the ability to unhide HNQ for the current session only?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, hot-questions

Actually, I like HNQ, and I'd love to see some of those questions from time to time. However, it's a distraction when I'm working, so I would like to disable it (when/where I'm working). In `Edit profile and settings > SITE SETTINGS > Preferences`, we have `Hide Hot Network Questions`, which is good. But after checking it, there is no way to unhide it when I don't mind seeing them (without going through the settings again and the possibility of forgetting to turn it back on afterward).

I would suggest that we either add:

- a collapsible HNQ pane that shows just a title and an unhide/expand button; or
- a per-browser HNQ setting

I know there are userscripts that do the same thing (hide/unhide), so why don't we make it part of this site?

Comment: I just noticed that https://stackexchange.com/ can be used to view HNQ regardless of the preference setting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply have the checkbox be copied to the sidebar as well, above the HNQ list:

> [image: Hot questions list with checkbox above it]

This is a simple UI, and it does not require extensive development or design work.

Comment: Is that checkbox value stored in a cookie?

Comment: @rene no, it's cross device, just checked now. Ticked the box on PC, and HNQ was also hidden on my mobile device. It's stored in a network level, so also doesn't appear to be Redis cache. Worth asking Nick how it works. :)

Comment: I think an expand/collapse button has the following advantage: 1) allows a default state to be set in profile settings 2) It's neat (either a [chevron-down](https://octicons.github.com/icon/chevron-down/)/chevron-right on the left, or a chevron-down/chevron-up on the right, just takes a single icon, and everybody knows what it does)